# Could not create multiple rows with header(of column and row) in Android

Tags: android, matrix, android-tablelayout

I have problem with creating header of column and row with respective cell values. Only show last position value in both column and row.

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

TableLayout ll = new TableLayout(this);
HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);

String[] row = { "ROW1", "ROW2", "Row3", "Row4", "Row 5", "Row 6", "Row 7" };
String[] column = { "COLUMN1", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN3", "COLUMN4", "COLUMN5", "COLUMN6" };

int nor = row.length;
int noc = column.length;

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Matrix Implemention Test");

for (int i = 0; i < nor; i++) 
{ // for rows
    TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);

    for (int j = 0; j <= noc; j++) 
    { // for columns
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        String s1 = Integer.toString(i);
        String s2 = Integer.toString(j);
        String s3 = s1 + s2;
        int id = Integer.parseInt(s3);

        //   tv1[i][j].setId(id);
        if (i == 0 & j==0) {
            tv1.setText("0=0");
            Log.d("TAH", "Display00!!!");
        } else if (i == 0) {
            for (int r = 0; r < nor; r++) {
                tv1.setText(row[r]);
                Log.d("TAG", "i==0->"+row[r]);
            }
        } else if (j == 0) {
            for (int c = 0; c < noc; c++) {
                tv1.setText(column[c]);
                Log.d("TAG", "j==0->"+row[c]);
            }
        } else {
            tv1.setText("Table Cell No=>>  " + id);
        }

        tbrow.addView(tv1);
    }

    ll.addView(tbrow);
}

hsv.addView(ll);
sv.addView(hsv);
setContentView(sv);
```

Output like this: I want of respective header of both column and row. first row 1, row 2.... and column 1, column 2....and so on. but only last position value display above code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change your code to:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < nor; i++) { // for row

            TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);

            for (int j = 0; j <= noc; j++) { // for column
                TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
                String s1 = Integer.toString(i);
                String s2 = Integer.toString(j);
                String s3 = s1 + s2;
                int id = Integer.parseInt(s3);
            //   tv1[i][j].setId(id);
                if (i == 0 & j==0) {
                    tv1.setText("0=0");
                    Log.d("TAH", "Display00!!!");
                } else if (i == 0) {

                        tv1.setText(column[j]);

                } else if (j == 0) {

                        tv1.setText(row[i]);

                } else {
                    tv1.setText("Table Cell No=>>  " + id);
                }
                tbrow.addView(tv1);
            }
            ll.addView(tbrow);
        }
```

First thing you seems to have confused columns with rows so i corrected that.

And second notice this for loop:

```
 for (int r = 0; r < nor; r++) {
                        tv1.setText(row[r]);
                        Log.d("TAG", "i==0->"+row[r]);
                    }
```

is missing.

Here you are first setting row[0] value to tv1 and then row[1] ... so on.

And in the end tv1 has row[6] as the last value.

Comment: it is not working, now first column1 and row 1 display all column or row header.